# How to get array which have some particular key

Tags: php, arrays, key

my array is

```
[newconfig_name] => 'abc',
[name] => 'xyz',
[newconfig_qty] => '200',
[qty] => '100'
```

i need data which have key same as newconfig

how to convert array like

```
[newconfig_name] => 'abc',
[newconfig_qty] => '200',
```

without any loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array_walk` function as

```
$result = array();
array_walk($array,function($v,$k)use(&$result){
if(strpos($k,'newconfig')>-1){ 
   $result[$k] = $v;
}});
```

[**Fiddle**](https://eval.in/382450)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this -

```
foreach($arr as $key => $val) {
   if(strpos($key, 'newconfig') === 0) {
       $new[$key] = $val;
   }
}
```

**Output**

```
array(2) {
  ["newconfig_name"]=>
  string(3) "abc"
  ["newconfig_qty"]=>
  string(3) "200"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use these lines of code.

```
foreach($yourarray as $key=>$value)
{
   if(strcmp($key, 'newconfig') == 0)
   {
     $yourarray[$key] = 'newvalue';
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
        $new_array = array();
        $my_key = "newconfig";
        $array = array(
                        'newconfig_name' => 'abc',
                        'name' => 'xyz',
                        'newconfig_qty' => '200',
                        'qty' => '100'
                       );
        foreach($array as $key => $data)
        {
            if( strpos($key , $my_key ) !== FALSE )
            {
                $new_array[$key] = $data;
            }
        }
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($new_array);
        echo "</pre>";
    ?>
```

[Check Demo Here](http://codepad.org/XtlN4ZbK)